# Use element with DOMNodeInserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For sure this question is very easy, but I just cannot figure this out.

I'm using `DOMNodeInserted` event to detect when a new element is inserted.

I don't know how to use the current element, for example to get it's parent id.

Now I have the function like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event){
  var element = event.target;

  if (element.tagName == 'DIV') {
    if (element.id == 'ndiv_3-1VTSTHR') {
     alert($('#ndiv_3-1VTSTHR').parent().get(0).tagName);
    }
  }
});
```

This works, but it will give me the parent to `ndiv_3-1VTSTHR` element. I want to know the parent to any element, using jQuery.

I tried with:

```
alert($(this).parent().get(0).tagName);
```

but with no luck.

Comment: What about removing the `if` for filtering a specific id? And then use `$(element)`.

Comment: @pimvdb: Nope, tried with alert($(element).tagName); and is giving me undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to initialize a jQuery object around `element.target`. Try:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).parent()[0].tagName);
});
```

Comment: Either `element` or `event.target` I think :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. But if I make var el = $(event.target).parent()[0]; can I use it further with alert($(el).tagName)?

Comment: @Parkyprg, `tagName` is a property exposed by DOM elements, not jQuery objects. You'd have to write either `el.tagName` or `$(el)[0].tagName`. It might be best to store the jQuery object itself in `el`: `var el = $(event.target).parent();`. From there you can do `el[0].tagName` to obtain the element's tag name.