# Getting Text from Newly Inserted Element

Tags: jquery, dom

How do I go about getting the text from a newly inserted element using DOMNodeInserted.

Example:

```
<div id='elementID'>
    <span class='elementClass'>Some text</span> <!-- already present -->
    <span class='elementClass'>Some text</span> <!-- already present -->
    <span class='elementClass'>Some text</span> <!-- newly inserted -->
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814219/jquery-use-element-with-domnodeinserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it via event.target

```
$('#elementID').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).text());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pccwc/