# jQuery event listener for the insertion of an element specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to dynamically add some CSS classes to some elements that I don't have control over the creation of. I know that the divs I'm looking for will be added like this: `mydiv.appendChild(resdiv)`. However, I cannot add code at that point at which they're created. I know that every instance of this div that is dynamically added will have a specific CSS class (let's call it `output-class`). I could theoretically add CSS rules to that specific class, but I'd rather not - it would result in the duplication of a lot of styles.

What I want to do is fire an event as soon as a div with the `output-class` class is added to the page. I'm trying to add some more CSS classes on the fly. Here's what I have so far:

```
jQuery('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', ".output-class", function(event) {
    var el = $(this);
    el.addClass('my new class');
    // do some more manipulation of the new div (el).
});
```

However, as far as I can tell, this callback is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814219/jquery-use-element-with-domnodeinserted

Comment: If your DOM elements are being added via an AJAX request success/complete callback, you can set up a global ajaxComplete event handler that checks for those elements being added.

Comment: Could help : http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/XaTCh/

Comment: Golly gee @DevlshOne! I already had a tab with that answer open, and I just skimmed it instead of actually reading it :(. That did it. If you make it an answer I'll accept. (Thanks to @sdespont too, that was also the right answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several related question involving DOM Insertion including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814219/jquery-use-element-with-domnodeinserted) which contains the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
    alert($(event.target).parent()[0].tagName);
});
```